# Selector for the first object after a given object

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to use jquery to select the first object in a list that follows a known object.

I have a document like this:

```
<div>A</div>
<div class="special">B</div>
<div>C</div>
<div>D</div>
<div>E</div>
```

I've run this previously:

```
foo = $(".special");
```

I want to run something like:

```
$( foo+" + div" );
```

To get back the div that contains "C".  This has got to be easy, but I can't figure out how to do it.

(Note: I know about $( ".special + div" ).  The problem is that I need to store ".special" as a variable.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the `next` method

```
foo = $(".special").next();
```

Documentation: http://api.jquery.com/next/

Fiddle Sample: http://jsfiddle.net/a5GWz/

Answer (score 0):

you can use [`next`](http://api.jquery.com/next/) along with [`:contains`](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)

```
foo = $(".special").next(":contains(C)");
```

here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/zPBv5/1/